# Unable to use easy_install to install Python modules

Tags: python, module, installation, setuptools, easy-install

I am trying to use `easy_install` to install a module called **requests** by doing

```
easy_install requests
```

This worked fine a week ago when I was using Python 2.6.5 but today I installed Python 2.7.2 and then tried to `import requests` in one of my scripts but it failed. I then tried reinstalling requests with `easy_install requests` but got this error

```
install_dir /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/test-easy-install-15207.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

So I was told to go reinstall easy_install and I went to http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools and learned I had to

> delete all setuptools*.egg and setuptools.pth files from your
>   system's site-packages directory (and any other sys.path directories)
>   FIRST.

So I did this. I then reinstalled setuptools from the `setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg`. It seemed successful but when I ran `easy_install requests` I got basically the same error except the directory python2.6/dist-packages is now python2.7/site-packages

```
siddhion@siddhion-laptop:~$ easy_install requests
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-16253.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Also, when I do `easy_install` and press tab I get these options

```
easy_install      easy_install-2.6  easy_install-2.7
```

How come easy_install-2.6 is there?

and

*How do I get easy-install working again?*

Answer (score 16):

Did you try using `sudo` like this?

```
sudo easy_install requests
```

Or specify the install directory to a directory that you have write privileges.

```
easy_install --install-dir=/home/foo/bar
```

But you should really use [PIP](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) instead of `easy_install`. It is much better and has a lot more features.

Comment: yes I did `sudo easy_install requests` but that did not work either. The point is that something is broken with my Python path it seems. easy_install or Python 2.7.2 is searching on the wrong paths I think. Like Python 2.7.2 is looking in the python2.6/dist-packages dir. Not sure.

Comment: I'm navigating this, too, and don't have `sudo` or I'd just use it.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `virtualenv` on package-based Linux distributions so Python scripts don't interfere with other packages or conflict with the OS's package-manager.

http://workaround.org/easy-install-debian

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me with Ubuntu 12.10 installing easy_install then [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html):

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding your new python.framework to path?
On mountain lion I added 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/`
to 
`/etc/paths`
and then I was able to use easy_install-3.3 and pip-3.3

Answer (score 2):

Using `Sudo` before `easy_install` may solve your problem

```
Sudo easy_install requests
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be a simple case of you missing "sudo" in the front.  Can you try it with sudo easy-install requests

putting the "sudo" will add the required permissions.